# How do I convert a text column to a timestamp column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a `text` column "`A`" in table X and I want to convert it to a `timestamp` column without a timezone in table Y.

How can I perform this conversion in PostgreSQL?

**Input**: Table X

| A (text) |
| --- |
| 2006-08-30 21:30:00 |
| 21:30:00 |

**Desired Output**: Table Y

| Output (timestamp) |
| --- |
| 2006-08-30 21:30:00 |
| 21:30:00 |

Comment: Use the function to_timestamp(): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html And you should fix the real problem, don't store data in the wrong datatype.

Comment: Date is mandatory part of timestamp https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-datetime.html  What is the date for the second value?

Comment: We are not getting date for the second row, we only have time for that second row. In the table we have rows with timestamp as well as row with only time in the same column

Comment: You 'd better provide a date value from some source.  Otherwise `to_timestamp('21:00:00', 'HH24:mi:ss')` == 0001-01-01 21:00:00 ..

Comment: You can't do that.  A timestamp has a date component.  You either provide the time component or Postgres makes one up for you.

Answer (score 1):

The TIME data type by itself is pretty much useless, which occurred first 23:00:00 or 01:00:00, without the date part you cannot tell. However you can get it what you want by applying cast twice: first string to timestamp then timestamp to time. Using Postgres cast operator (::) that becomes: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=987452e834fc2c3b8458bd45202d8f20))

```
select ts_as_string::timestamp::time from table_x;
```

NOTES: First, heed the comment by @FrankHeikens and use the proper data type for your timestamp and **not text**. You can virtually guarantee that at some point someone will insert an invalid value in that column (like 'N/A' perhaps) and Postgres will not stop it after all you declared it valid.  Second, Postgres 9.5 reached [end-of-life](https://endoflife.software/applications/databases/postgresql) in Feb 2021. You should update your version.